# java gis library

Tags: gis, arcgis, java

What is the best/user friendly GIS/arcGIS Java library for basic academic assignment?

Comment: I would love something that I could use to turn Township Range and Section into GPS or Lat/Long coords - that would be awesome!  Anything along these lines would be interesting however.

Comment: You need a library and not an application right?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it myself - but you might start by taking a look at GeoTools:

http://www.geotools.org/

Sample app tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-kmlservice/index.html?ca=drs-

Answer (score 4):

Java Topology Suite is a good option for 2D spatial operations.
http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm

Answer (score 4):

Esri released our Java Geometry engine under the open-source apache license.

https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java

It should cover most, if not all, of the geometry operations that you need.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Geotoolkit](http://www.geotoolkit.org/) - abridged as Geotk

> Geotk is the reference implementation of GeoAPI 3.0 interfaces.
>   ...
>   Geotk provides data structures for geographic data and associated
>   metadata along with methods to manipulate those data structures.

Answer (score 2):

gdal for java using swig

http://www.gdal.org/

gdal is a translator library for raster and vector geospatial data formats that is released under an X/MIT style Open Source license by the Open Source Geospatial Foundation. As a library, it presents a single raster abstract data model and single vector abstract data model to the calling application for all supported formats. It also comes with a variety of useful command line utilities for data translation and processing. The NEWS page describes the January 2017 GDAL/OGR 2.1.3 release.