# What is a good data structure for a multi resolution graph?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a data set consisting of hundreds of millions of data points.  I'd like to be able to effectively render such a set depending on the zoom level (i.e. axis scale).  I'd like to be able to have a sampled subset render at the full view.  As you zoom in, you'll be able to see more detailed data points until you reach maximum zoom, at that point you'll be able to see individual data points.  What would be a good data structure to store such a data set and allows multi resolution access?

Comment: Perhaps an image pyramid ?

Comment: Where do you get the data from. Do you load them dynamically?

Comment: @aDoubleSo yes, I have a DB backend that provides the data

Comment: You could use a kind of smoothing algorithm to reduce the data. More zoom less smoothing.

Comment: @aDoubleSo that would still require me to go through the entire dataset, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Does the whole data changing regularly - otherwise you could do some pre rendered resolutions.

Comment: @aDoubleSo it does get updated as time passes

Comment: Think I would grab every X frame and using bezier curves. When zoomed I would reduce the frame distance. Just a very simple idea.

Comment: Do the data-points already come with their positions, or do you plan on calculating those? Are there any edges that you wish to render?

Comment: @tucuxi its a time series, so yes the positions are already there.  I would like to show outliers if they exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep your points spatially indexed, because "outlier" and "density" are spatial properties -- an outlier is a point that happens to be in a low-density area; and "zooming out" would mean replacing sets of close-together points for 'sampled' points; and when "zooming in" you really, really want to ignore all those points that fall outside the current window. Your operations could be something like:

```
void addPoint(Point2D p);
void removePoint(Point2D p);
Iterator<Point2D> getPointsToPaint(Rectangle2D viewArea, int maxDensity, double densityArea);
```

where the `viewArea` represents the window you want to find points for, and the `maxDensity` parameter could be used to control point abstraction: when more than maxDensity points fall within a `densityArea` square, you return `maxDensity` random points within that area instead. `getPointsToPaint` would then cover your `viewArea` with `densityArea` sampling boxes and return the points within: the real points if less than `maxDensity`, and the "sampled" ones if over `maxDensity` (nobody will notice if 10 points within a 1mm2 area are random or not).

Typical spatial structures are [quad-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (for 2d) and [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Operations_on_k-d_trees) (for any number of ds). However, in their default implementations, neither of them is too good for quickly-changing dynamic data. Another option is to use [spatial hashing](http://themonkeyproject.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/introduction-to-spatial-hashes/); but you really seem to need a multi-level approach, and for multi-level, trees are always the way to go. From a quick review of search results for "*dynamic spatial indexing*", it seems that a variant of the [r-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) may be what you are looking for. Beware that these data-structures are not easy to implement from scratch. The best approach may be to rely on an external GIS system to do the bookkeeping for you. Several [Java GISs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404492/java-gis-library) are available.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what kind of data you are rendering, but I guess you could do sampling and calculate an approximation, and as you zoom in you make the approximation more and more accurate?

Comment: Depending on the dataset, guaranteeing that the sampling does not miss on "important points" can be hard. In particular, a sampling that does not discard outliers requires outliers to have been preemptively identified